# Import my SSH key as GPG sub-key to use for SSH authentication

Tags: ssh, gpg

I recently created a PGP key to sign my commits and it's working properly. I also discovered that gpg integrates better with my O.S. (Kubuntu) than ssh-agent.

I'm lazy and would like to avoid having to replace my SSH key in all the various servers I've access to.

Is there any option for me to import my existing SSH key as a subkey of my PGP key and then run gpg agent with ssh-agent support so that when I run `ssh something` it uses my subkey and uses gpg agent to ask for the passphrase?

Ideally I supply the passhprase only once, for my main PGP key and then whenever I commit or login through ssh, it uses the right one.

Is it possible? (I know they are different format, but that's really all I know)

Answer (score 7):

**All that you need:**

```
export GPG_TTY=$(tty)
export SSH_AUTH_SOCK=$(gpgconf --list-dirs agent-ssh-socket)
ssh-add -c -t 3600 ~/.ssh/id_rsa   # set the cache lifetime as 3600s
```

---

Then feel free to remove the files: `mv ~/.ssh/id_rsa.* /path/to/backup`.

Now you can do an SSH login for testing.

After all, remember to add the Environments to your profile, like `.profile` or `~/.bashrc`.

---

(Ps:You can find the ssh key(in gpg format) exists in `~/.gnupg/private-keys-v1.d/` and with keygrip as its name, which can be used to be added as a subkey.

**Reference:**

https://incenp.org/notes/2015/gnupg-for-ssh-authentication.html

https://www.gnupg.org/documentation/manuals/gnupg/Invoking-GPG_002dAGENT.html

Comment: Excellent reply. By, far the easiest I've seen.

Answer (score 6):

Found an easy approach. You need `pem2openpgp` utility from monkeysphere project and `gpg2`'s ability to import existing key as subkey.

First convert SSH key to OpenPGP format. You have to privode a new user ID as required by GPG.

```
$ pem2openpgp $TEMP_USERID < .ssh/id_rsa | gpg2 --import
```

Now you have a new user ID with your SSH key as master key. You can check it with `gpg2 -K` (I set `TEMP_USERID` to `TEST`). Also write down keygrip of newly imported key:

```
$ gpg2 -K --with-keygrip $TEMP_USERID
sec   rsa4096 2018-03-02 [C]
      21C766CAC691F395D640E8207E9F9F883D1E49D8
      Keygrip = AAB27E63622E87B27AC34293EDF52C3AB016CA2E
uid           [ unknown] TEST
```

Now use `gpg2 --expert --edit-key` on your master key and import above key as your subkey:

```
$ gpg2 --expert --edit-key $YOURUSERID
gpg> addkey
......
(13) Existing key
Enter the keygrip: AAB27E63622E87B27AC34293EDF52C3AB016CA2E
......
```

`gpg2` will ask you lots of questions as usual. Remember to toggle correct key capabilities (sign: off, encrypt: off, auth: on).

After this you should have the imported SSH key as your master key's subkey. Check it:

```
$ gpg2 -K $YOURUSERID --with-keygrip
sec   rsa4096 2016-02-02 [SC]
......
uid           [ 绝对 ] CUI Hao (cvhc) <cuihao.leo@gmail.com>
......
ssb   rsa4096 2018-02-21 [A]
      Keygrip = AAB27E63622E87B27AC34293EDF52C3AB016CA2E
```

You can use `gpg2 --export-ssh-key` to verify the imported subkey is indeed the same as original SSH key.

Note that the temporary user id used for key import is still in your keyring. You must delete it manually. GnuPG prevent you from removing public key / user id without deleting corresponding private keys. However, since the temporary user and your imported subkey share shares the same private key, `gpg2 --delete-secret-keys $TEMP_USERID` also deletes imported subkey.

My solution is to backup private keys in `~/.gnupg/private-keys-v1.d` and move it back after `gpg2` removed imported subkey.

I submit a feature request to ask GnuPG for an option to delete the public key without affecting private key: https://dev.gnupg.org/T3808